# Random point from triangle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that you randomly (with uniform distribution) choose point from triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$. What is the CDF of $\xi = \vert x-y \vert$, mean and variance of $\xi$?

Same question for triangle $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $\xi = \vert x+y \vert$.

I obtained $F_\xi(t) = t^2, ~0<t<1$ and $M\xi = \frac{2}{3}$, $D\xi = \frac{1}{18}$ for the first one. For the second the answers are same: $F_\xi(t) = t^2, ~0<t<1$ and $M\xi = \frac{2}{3}$, $D\xi = \frac{1}{18}$.

**Update**: Explanation below.

Since $F\xi(t) = \frac{(t^2)/2}{1/2} = t^2$ from geometry, $\rho_\xi(t) = \frac{d}{dt}F_\xi(t) = 2t$. Then $M\xi = \int_0^1 t\rho_\xi(t)dt = \frac{2}{3}$ and $D\xi = \int_0^1 (t-M\xi)^2\rho_\xi(t)dt = \frac{1}{18}$.

Am I right?

Comment: Tangentially related: Perhaps google Sierpinski Triangle or start with the [_Wikipedia article_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** In your second triangle, what is the need to take the absolute value?  Your math seems straightforward and correct.

As an informal reality check, I did a simulation in R statistical software of ten million
points at random in the unit square, 'accepting' the ones in your triangle (about five million).
Results agree with yours within simulation error. $D = X + Y = |X+Y| \sim
\mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$

```
set.seed(1017)
m = 10^7; x = runif(m);  y = runif(m)
acc = x+y < 1
ax = x[acc];  ay = y[acc]
d = ax + ay
mean(d);  var(d)
## 0.6666399
## 0.05555616
```

[image]